# Mongodb how to bulk insert from javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to insert data to mongodb collection. I am running in a loop where getting below sample data in each iteration,

```
13:24:24:007,Peter,male,3720,yes
13:24:24:007,John,female,1520,yes
13:24:24:023,John,female,9720,yes
13:24:24:023,Mario,male,9820,no
13:24:24:023,Katy,male,4320,no
13:24:24:038,John,male,3620,no
```

These data is for field names ,

```
currenttime, custname, gender, custid, ismember
```

I want to insert the data into mongodb collection with appropriate field name. I am not getting any idea how to use mongodb bulk insert in my requirement.

One option i have that, i can take this data in a array variable (spilt by new line) and take each item of this array to another array (split by comma) and make a object in loop , and finally insert that object into mongodb collection. But this approach  looks very simple and slow. I strongly believe there must be some better way to do this. Please suggest.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/

Comment: You might want to check out [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/index.html)

Comment: I haven't tried mongoimport. will check it now. One ques , can we use mongoimport for a file which is growing continuously ?

Comment: Yes, you can specify [these options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-mode) when running the command

Comment: I have gone through the <these options> but didn't find any option to take care of running/growing file. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly insert the array using insert function if your result before running the loop is somewhat like this.

```
    var data= [{currenttime:13:24:24:007,
        custname:"Peter", 
        gender:"male", 
        custid:"3720", 
        ismember:"yes"},
        {currenttime:13:24:24:007, 
        custname:"John",
        gender:"male", 
        custid:"1520",
        ismember:"yes"}
    ]

    db.collection.insert(data,function(err,data){
      if(!err){
             //send sucess message
      }else{
       //send a failure message
      }
})
```